Interest rate models history
I am familiar with some interest rate models, such as the Vasicek, CIR. I also have an understanding of the basic formalization of other models such as Ho-Lee, Hull-White, HJM, Libor market model (LMM). Currently, I am studying the FMM model proposed by Lyashchenko and Mercurio in their seminal paper.
What I want to understand is the overall picture of interest rate modeling and the place of each model in it. I believe that this issue must be considered from a historical perspective in order to understand why certain models appeared and what what advantages they brought.
Now I see the history of interest rate models as follows:

equilibrium models (Vasicek, CIR)
no-arbitrage models (Ho-Lee, Hull-White, ...)
multifactor models (Chen, ..)
HJM framework
Libor market model (LMM)
Forward Market Model (FMM)

The bottom line is that I strive for a exhaustive understanding of what idea lies behind each model (class of models) and why some models were preferred over time over others. Which of the listed models have been heavily used in investment banking practice?


was mainly academic and was not much used in practice, 2. was the first generation of models in wide use imho. Later on 5 became the most popular.

